# Homestead / VirtualBox & MariaDB

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, mariadb, homestead

I would like to 'adjust' Laravel Homestead and install MariaDB on the VM instead of MySQL. What is the best way to do that without having a lot of experience with VMs so far?

Thanks!

Comment: Homestead has Ubuntu as its OS. It will be better if you search for how to install MariaDB in Ubuntu.

Comment: Already have tried to install from the console when the VM is booted. Got all kind of errors. Would like to install MariaDB when the VM is booted instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

There's `after.sh` script under `~/.homestead` directory which you could use to further provision the VM.
Replace the contents of `after.sh` with this bash script to replace MySQL with MariaDB.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove mysql server
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --yes remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-server mysql-community-client
sudo apt-get --yes autoremove
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoclean

# install mariadb server 10.1
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository --yes 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://mirror.zol.co.zw/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
sudo apt-get update -q
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.1 mysql-server/root_password password secret'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password secret'
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

This will create a user `root` with password `secret`. To verify the installation, ssh to vagrant machine and try `mysql -u root -p`. 
Also, note that this script will remove hhvm.